Monodromy action on the period domain in the Lawrence-Venkatesh paper
Let $Y\longrightarrow X$ be a smooth proper map of smooth quasiprojective schemes over $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
In Lawrence and Venkatesh's paper on Mordell-Weil, the authors consider the $p$-adic period map: $\Phi_p: \Omega_p\longrightarrow\mathcal{H}$, whose domain is a residue disk of $X$, and its target is a certain flag variety whose points encode the different filtrations of a fixed shape, over some fixed $d$-dimensonal $\mathbb{Z}_p$-vector space.
The map is defined by sending a point $x\in \Omega_p$ to the Hodge filtration of $H^1_{\text{dR}}(Y_x, \mathbb{Q}_p)$, i.e. the fibre of $Y$ over $x$.
In their paper, they claim that points which share isomorphic Tate modules above them differ by 'an action of Frobenius centralizers', and that 'their number is finite if the dimension of Frobenius centralizers is smaller than the dimension of the monodromy'.
Can anyone explain these two statements?
It seems as if there is an implicit faithful action of the monodromy group on the period domain. Is that true? How is this action defined? Why is this action faithful?
Thanks in advance.
